# Is making field.tpl.php print the URL of the node the displayed field is attached to possible?

Tags: 7, entities, theming

Currently I have this setup with Views but I would like to take views out of the picture to optimize the site and fix a couple of problems that occure as a result of using Views.

What I am trying to achieve is if my nodes have content in a Body of Text called excerpt that it will show a button that links to the node's url and append the text "/excerpt" at the end of the node's url which will then display a different page with the content of excerpt on it.

I'm using Drupal 7 and am modifying a Zen subtheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is`<?php print drupal_get_path_alias("node/".$element['#object']->nid); ?>`

This will print the URL Alias of the node that the respective field is attached to.

I found that I could get the NID of the node the element was attached to by doing`<?php print_r($element['#object']);?>`to find all of the available options for`<?php $element['#object']?>`when I found I could get the NID from that field I then put it inside of`<?php drupal_get_path_alias() ?>`and have it return the desired text.

It took a day to find it but it works. Hopefully someone else can benefit from this as well.